# Why can I not use children array here? Flutter

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-layout

I have this class, taken and changed from one of the examples

```
class SignUpView extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignUpView({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 400,
          child: Card(
            child: SignUpForm(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But if I want to put children , instead of child, like this

```
class SignUpView extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignUpView({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 400,
            child: Card(
              child: SignUpForm(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It says The named parameter children isn't defined.

What if I want to put more than one child in the Center container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center can only have a single child. Use something like `Column`, `Row`, or a `ListView` to use more than 1 widget for Center.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignUpView extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignUpView({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 400,
              child: Card(
                child: SignUpForm(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out. Flutter Community is amazing :D

Comment: Yes, I think so too

Comment: Is there a place where I can see how many children a widget can have for all widgets, and what can be nested in what?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout